# Sitecore How to Know If Workflow process is done (Approved state and published)

Tags: sitecore, workflow

I'd like to know if Workflow process is done or not.

What I wanted to do is:
I created an assembly and once Workflow process is in Final state or Auto-Publish work is done, execute the method in the assembly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <events>
            <!-- Once Workflow autoPublish is done, do this for CDN -->
            <event name="publish:complete:remote">
                <handler type="My.Class.Name, Assembly.Name" method="MethodName">
                </handler>
            </event>
        </events>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

How can I do this??

Comment: Every workflow command could have actions. Is it an option for you to add action to command that moves item to final workflow step?

Comment: @Anton No. the assembly is about my customized event which is about cache. If I can add multiple assemblies in Action field. It would be great.

Comment: you can add a lot of actions under one command. One of them could contain your method and your assembly.

Comment: @Anton I updated my question. Once workflow auto-publishing is done, remotePublish event would fires. Then, execute the handler.

Comment: I still don't understand why not to add once more action under Auto-Publish action. All actions under your command are executed in a pipeline way, one by one. So, action under Auto-Publish will be exact right place to do something right after Auto-Publish.

Comment: @Anton I'm trying. Thx!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All action that you have under workflow command work in a similar way as regular pipelines and processors that you have in your configuration files. But in this case command is pipeline and action is processor.

So, to execute something just after Auto-Publish command you should add another one command after Auto-Publish command. This new command should contain link to method that you to execute.

Comment: will this require manual intervention? That is, clicking on the command after the Auto-Publish has completed?

Comment: yes, it requires. But without command clicking (if you directly change workflow state) Auto-Publish also will not be called. If question is about workflows then it should be done via additional action. If question is about any publishing then you should use events.

P.S. Even without manual intervention you could call workflow command programmatically. Then all command actions will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really want. Do you want to know that the particular item has passed the workflow or do you also want to know that the async publish action has completed? Defining an additional action after the auto publish is definitely the easiest way. Adding an event handler is also possible but more complex since the event handler will be triggered for each item / site publish. How are you going to differentiate?

I see you're using the publish:**complete**:remote event but I wonder if Sitecore even uses it. HtmlCacheClearing for example is running in the publish:**end**:remote event.

Comment: publish:complete:remote is being called, but only in the latest versions. There was a bug after the introduction of the event that prevented it from being called.